# Why is count(*) returning multiple results in this subquery (postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to group the results of a count(*) query into value buckets. I'm testing this on the dellstore2 postgresql sample database. My query below returns the right answers, but does so once for each row in the table (several thousand identical results). I can fix this by adding `LIMIT 1` the the end of the query but I'd like to understand why I'm getting the duplicates in case it points to a wider problem with my approach. The query is:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*)
        FROM
            orders
        WHERE
            totalamount > 0 AND totalamount <= 100) AS ">0 <= 100",
    (SELECT count(*)
        FROM
            orders
        WHERE
            totalamount > 100 AND totalamount <= 200) AS ">100 <= 200"
...
FROM
    orders;
```

EDIT
Andomar's answer also allowed me to find the following approach (adapted from an example in SQL in a nutshell (O'Reilly)). This lets me have the buckets in one column, with a row for each bucket/answer pairing. I thought I'd include it for anyone with that use-case:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN totalamount IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
        WHEN totalamount <= 100 THEN 'Not more than 100'
        WHEN totalamount <= 200 THEN 'Not more than 200'
        ELSE 'Over 200'
    END "Bucket",
    COUNT(*) "Number of results"
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN totalamount IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
        WHEN totalamount <= 100 THEN 'Not more than 100'
        WHEN totalamount <= 200 THEN 'Not more than 200'
        ELSE 'Over 200'
    END
ORDER BY
    MIN(totalamount);
```

Comment: It seems there are a few closing parentheses missing. Please post the real code.

Comment: Thanks wildplasser — now fixed (I'm working across two unconneted machines so couldn't cut and paste).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're selecting every row from `orders`, and then for each row, the subqueries are evaluated.

Consider this approach instead:

```
select  count(case when 0 < totalamount and totalamount <= 100 then 1 end)
            as "<0,100]"
,       count(case when 100 < totalamount and totalamount <= 200 then 1 end)
            as "<100,200]"
from    Orders
```

This would calculate both aggregates in a single table scan.

Comment: Thanks Andomar, that's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Because you included them as a subquery. From the looks of it, both the count subqueries are executed for each row in the `orders` table. If you omit the `from` piece from the main query you should only get one row.

For example, the query

```
SELECT 'John Doe' FROM orders
```

returns 'John Doe' for each row in the orders table.

```
SELECT 'John Doe'
```

only selects one row.

*Disclaimer: this is sql server behaviour.*

Comment: Thanks Jesse, this worked but I've ticked Andomar's solution above because I felt his approach to the query was more readable than my original.